# Javascript: want to run my Bookmarklet infinite time

Tags: javascript, loops, bookmarklet, bookmarks, infinite

I have one boomarklet, means javascript code that takes current page's source, search for one string (or i can say hyperlink) and changes the current page to gathered link.

The problem is that

> i want to make it run infinite times, if possible pausing in between to let the page load.

*This is for just one of RPG i am playing, i am bored of Clicking that Exchange Flower link
again and again and again.* 
and its not offensive, or i ca say not ethical, they have many bookmarklets for doing some other kinda work, so ..

here is the Code
`javascript:window.location.href=document.documentElement.innerHTML.substring(document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("museum.php?rfc="),document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("museum.php?rfc=")+18)+"&step=a2";`

Thanks anyway...

Comment: What code have you got so far? It is probably as simple as just calling `setTimeout()` at the end of your function on itself. Or is the bookmarklet navigating (its hard to tell from your question)?

Comment: here is the Code
`javascript:window.location.href=document.documentElement.innerHTML.substring(document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("museum.php?rfc="),document.documentElement.innerHTML.indexOf("museum.php?rfc=")+18)+"&step=a2";`

Comment: You should really put that in your questions

Comment: Does the answer below not meet some criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are asking about running some javascript on page load, since the script is navigating the page. Tools like [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (for Firefox) are built for just this.

For Google Chrome, you could try t[his tool](http://sandbox.self.li/bookmarklet-to-extension/) which converts bookmarklets into extensions.

Comment: A good Chrome form of GreaseMonkey called TamperMonkey. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

Comment: Cool, I hadn't seen that before